# Remove header in a3 pages inside a4 doc

Tags: header-footer, longtable

I have a longtable in a3 pages within an a4 document. I want to remove the headers since these pages are going to be one sided and the header is for a two sided document. I have tried different things but none seems to work. Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{book}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{emptypage}
    \usepackage[twoside, right=3cm, hmarginratio=1:1, top=4cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{appendix}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt} % space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\huge}    [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{60pt}



\begin{document}

\newenvironment{hugepage}
{\clearpage \changepage{}{210mm}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}} % switch to A3 
{\clearpage \changepage{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}}

\afterpage{%
\begin{hugepage}
\pdfpagewidth=2\pdfpagewidth

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Apéndices}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\thispagestyle{empty}
\appendix 
\addappheadtotoc
\chapter{Huge Table}
\label{apenA}

\begingroup
    \fontsize{7pt}{11pt}\selectfont
    \begin{longtable}{| r | l | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c| c | c | c | c | c| c|}
        \caption{Huge table.} \label{tablatodas} \\     

    \toprule
            {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c1}}} & {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c2}}} & {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{cc3}}} & {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c4}}} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}             {\textbf{c5}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c6}}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c7}}} &  \textbf{c8} & \textbf{c9} &  \textbf{c10}                      & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c11}}  & \textbf{c12} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c13}}& \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c14}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c15}}          &  \textbf{c16} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c17}} \\

        &   &   &  &  & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}}} &  {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b.}}} & \textbf{b} &  \textbf{b} &  \textbf{b}  & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}} &  \textbf{b} &  & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}}  &  \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}} &  \textbf{b} & \\

        &   &   &  &  &  &  & \textbf{c} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{c} &  & \textbf{c} &  &  &  &  \textbf{c} &  \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{17}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continuación}} \\

    \toprule
            {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c1}}} & {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c2}}} & {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{cc3}}} & {\multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c4}}} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}             {\textbf{c5}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c6}}} & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c7}}} &  \textbf{c8} & \textbf{c9} &  \textbf{c10}                      & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c11}}  & \textbf{c12} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c13}}& \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c14}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{c15}}          &  \textbf{c16} & \multirow{3}[2]{*}{\textbf{c17}} \\

        &   &   &  &  & {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}}} &  {\multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b.}}} & \textbf{b} &  \textbf{b} &  \textbf{b}  & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}} &  \textbf{b} &  & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}}  &  \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{b}} &  \textbf{b} & \\

        &   &   &  &  &  &  & \textbf{c} & \textbf{c} & \textbf{c} &  & \textbf{c} &  &  &  &  \textbf{c} &  \\
    \midrule
    \endhead

    \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot


AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa \\
AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa & AAAaaaa     \end{longtable}%
\endgroup

\end{hugepage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue

```
\pagestyle{plain}
```

or

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

for the pages in which you want no fancy headers/footers. For just one page, you can use `\thispagestyle{plain}`.